# Can I combine SQL statements in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application code looks like this:

```
using SQLite;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

...
...

    db2.Execute("DELETE FROM Phrase" +
                " WHERE PhraseId NOT IN(SELECT Id FROM PhraseSource)");
    db2.Execute("DELETE FROM Phrase" +
                " WHERE Modified < (SELECT Modified FROM PhraseSource WHERE Id = Phrase.PhraseId)");
    db2.Execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Phrase(CategoryId, PhraseId, English, Romaji, Kana, Kanji, Modified)" +
                " SELECT PS.CategoryId, PS.ID, PS.English, PS.Romaji, PS.Kana, PS.Kanji, PS.Modified" +
                " FROM PhraseSource AS PS");
```

Can these three statements be combined into one? Also is there a way that I could rollback if any of them were to fail? Do I need to follow the statements with a ";" if they can be combined or using a "go" or something like that?

Comment: Did you try to follow the statements with a semicolon and then combining the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite executes every command in separate transaction. You just need to run it in one and then rollback if something goes wrong:

```
 try
 {
     db2.BeginTransaction();
     //executions go here
     db2.Commit();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     db2.Rollback();
 }
```

Regarding combining queries, if you want to combine them for rollback purposes then my example will do just fine, you can leave your code as it is. If not then just combine them with semicolon in one string.